# what is Jordan basis for a matrix? and is JCF useful in practice?

Tags: linear-algebra

I met a linear algebra problem: Our field is complex number, find the Jordan basis for the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
0& 1 & 2&3\\ 
0 &0&1&2\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

I think this problem is related Jordan Canonical Form, but I haven't learnt the term "Jordan basis". What is this? Thank you very much!

Another unrelated question: JCF and the rational form are useless in practice, right? SVD is more useful, right? I saw a lot of applications of SVD, like image compression, PCA, recommender systems, etc. But I have never, never, seen any applications of JCF or the rational form.

Comment: what do you mean by "in practice"? both the JFC and the RCF are very useful when solving systems of differential/difference equations. see, for example, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655030/inverse-of-a-symmetric-tridiagonal-matrix/659623#659623
, where I resort to the JCF to solve a system of linear difference equations.

Comment: You are right, it can be used to calculate matrix exponentials. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Jordan basis is a basis in which the matrix is in Jordan Canonical Form.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, it is the collection of all the Jordan blocks(for each eigenvalue)?